# Ruby - Delay code

Tags: ruby

I want to initiate this Twilio phone call from my Ruby Sinatra script **5 minutes from now**. What is the best/easiest way to do that?

```
@call = @client.account.calls.create(
    :from => '+11231231234',
    :to => '+13333333333',     
    :url => 'response.xml'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) gem, which allows you to delay any code in ruby:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.in '5m' do
  # do something in 5 minutes
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) gem is a:

> Rufus-scheduler (out of the box) is an in-process, in-memory scheduler.
>
> It does not persist your schedules. When the process is gone and the scheduler instance with it, the schedules are gone.

Similar solutions for asynchronous code execution, including timed events, include the [eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) gem and the [iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) gem (which I'm biased towards).

If you're using the `Thin` server, you're already running EventMachine, might as well use it. The same goes for the `Iodine` server and it's own reactor pattern.

On the other hand, if you need something that is persistent even after the initiating process is finished, look into [Sidekiq with Redis](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis)

Answer (score 0):

For background jobs you need additional process and queue storage(redis), most popular libraries is:

- Rescue https://github.com/resque/resque
- Sidekiq https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq